# Django Model - check validity of the models

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am new to **Django - ORM** and facing issues with creating relations .
The db is **SQLite** .

I am trying to solve following problem present -

> A User will add different Skills to his/her profile .S/He can also
>   create new skills which were earlier not present and can add to the
>   profile .
>
> Other users can upvote the skills on user profile - this should be
>   recorded in Database too .

Uptill not I have created following model

```
   #import from django models module
from django.db import models

# This class will more or less map to a table in the database and defines skills at the application level
class Skill (models.Model):
    # this defines a required name that cannot be more than 100 characters.
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "wantedly_webapp"

# This class will more or less map to a table in the database and defines the many to many relationship between user-skill, this is our intermediate model
class UserSkill(models.Model):
    """ A Model for representing skill in user profile """
    unique_together = (('user', 'skill_item'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Define a foreign key relating this model to the Skill model.
    # The parent user will be able to access it's skills with the related_name
    # 'all_user_skills'. When a parent is deleted, this will be deleted as well. 
    skill_item = models.ForeignKey(
        Skill,
        related_name='all_user_skills', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.skill_item.skill_name)

# this class adds a Many to Many field in existing django-rest auth UserProfile class for  user and his/her skills 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User',unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_skills = models.ManyToManyField(
            Skill,
            through='UserSkill',
            through_fields=('user','skill_item')
        )

class UserSkillUpvotes(models.Model):
    unique_together = (('user_skill', 'upvote_by'),)
    user_skill = models.OneToOneField('UserSkill',unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvote_by =  models.OneToOneField('auth.User',unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have created models now , next I need help on how to test this and update if anything is required for operations like

1. Adding new skill
2. Adding existing skill to user profile
3. Saving up-votes of skill on current user profile by other users etc

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I removed it but still same error

Comment: [N+1 queries are not a problem with SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/np1queryprob.html).

Comment: @CL that was interesting read . Can you please help me in testing this model ?